# UIScrollView setContentOffset back to top, stop at incorrect contentOffset

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have a button at the top of `UITableView`, once I tap the button, will call `setContentOffset(:animated:)` of this `UITableView` to back to the contentOffset I want, which is `-button.height`.

Most of time it works, while since my tableView support paging, when I scroll down the tableView, it will load more data after request finish. here is the issues happened, after I loading the second page,
I call this method again when I tap the button,`setContentOffset(:animated:)`, it will stop in another offset location. I guess it might related to some bouncing stuff, anyone knows the answer, thanks~

**Update**

Figure out the root cause is my UITableView's cell's height is automatic height, `estimatedRowHeight = automaticDimension`

based on Apple's doc

```
When using height estimates, 
the table view actively manages the contentOffset and contentSize properties inherited from its scroll view. 
Do not attempt to read or modify those properties directly.
```

so I give up to call `setContentOffset(:animated:)` directly, instead of I use `scrollToRow`

Comment: The question is not so clear, what do you mean by `load more after second page` and also please add your code to the question of the things you mention in your question which might help someone understand the problem better.

Comment: Please share with us your code, so it is just a guess now, but I think you need the scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:). or setContentOffset(_:animated:).

Comment: Hi thanks for your guys' response,  I update the description. hope can get more clarify.